# Adding 30 days to the converted date is giving me Invalid Date message in browser's console log

Tags: javascript, date

I have converted the timestamp `4/1/2021 00:00` into the format   `Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)` as shown in the code below. However, adding 30 days is not giving me appropriate result.

```js
 
    
//Handling Date String: 4/1/2021 00:00
function setStart(input) {
        if (!(input instanceof Date))
            console.log('Handling Date String:' +input)
            input = new Date(Date.parse(input));

        input.setHours(0);
        input.setMinutes(0);
        input.setSeconds(0);
        input.setMilliseconds(0);

        start = input;
        return start;        
    }
 
var initialDate = setStart('4/1/2021 00:00'); 
console.log("Printing converted date below:"); 
console.log(setStart('4/1/2021 00:00'));


var date = new Date(); // Now
//date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30); // Set now + 30 days as the new date
date.setDate(initialDate + 30);
console.log("Printing date after adding 30 days below")
console.log(date);


/* var getDaysArray = function(start, end) {
    for(var arr=[],dt=new Date(start); dt<=new Date(end); dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)){
        arr.push(new Date(dt));
    }
    return arr;
};

var daylist = getDaysArray(new Date("2018-05-01"),new Date("2018-06-01"));

console.log(daylist); */
```

The browser's console is printing it like the following:

```
Handling Date String:4/1/2021 00:00
Printing converted date below:
Handling Date String:4/1/2021 00:00
Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
Printing date after adding 30 days below
Invalid Date
```

What is causing it to print `Invalid Date` ?

Comment: your code is adding 1617195600000 days to the date - that's over 4 billion YEARS

Comment: `new Date(input)` will produce an identical result to `new Date(Date.parse(input))`, but use fewer keystrokes. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the date after 30 days from the initialDate, don't you?
refer this

```js
var date = new Date(initialDate); // Now
//date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30); // Set now + 30 days as the new date
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30);
console.log("Printing date after adding 30 days below")
console.log(date);
```

Comment: thank you. This works based on my requirement. Looks like I was not writing  this part `date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30);` properly.

Comment: You can read more about Date Object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date). Its constructor accepts other Date Object.

p/s: Could you 'vote up' for me to get more reputation? I don't have enough reputation to 'vote up' anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You should something like

```js
var date = new Date().getTime(); // Now
const offset = 30*23*3600*1000;
const newDate = new Date(date+offset).toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'CST'}); // Change added
console.log("Printing date after adding 30 days below")
console.log(newDate);
```

Comment: So in my case, how should  I make the already converted date `Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)` such that it's easy to add `30` days to it?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, check the modified answer and see if it helps